# How do you measure GPU throttling?

Tags: windows, performance, gpu, temperature

How do I determine or monitor when and to what extend my GPU throttles due to thermal constraints?

Is this data available natively in logs or do I need to run a separate program beyond what is included with Nvidia drivers?

If the latter, is it a matter of simply monitoring clock frequency and temperature or are there other throttling mechanisms that do not affect clock frequency?

I want to ensure that my case has adequate cooling.

*Note*: the OS is Windows 8 Pro with discrete graphics (Nvidia GTX 670).

Answer (score 7):

I would use the program [GPU-z](http://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/). It has real time monitoring of your GPU and you can have it create a log file to go back and review later. If the GPU is throttling itself, there will be a clear drop in Core Clock usually because of the high GPU temps.

The things it monitors:

- Core Clock
- Memory Clock
- GPU Temps
- Fan Speed
- Fan RPM
- Memory Usage
- GPU Usage
- How much current it is using

Comment: So, the GPU does not throttle itself in any way other than lowering the core clock frequency?

Comment: That is correct.